# How to pass Authorization token in a React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on the react part of a web app with NodeJs as backend. I'm having issue with passing authorization after login action. When a user logs in, a token is generated and I take this token and save it in the local storage. Then I use it to control users on the website with the below code:

```
    const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) =>(
      <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        window.localStorage.token !== undefined
         ? <Component {...props} />
         : <Redirect to="/" />
    )} />
```

Now this works well, but when I try to make a post request to the server, I get the below error:

```
  { type: "ValidationError", details: "Authorization token not passed"}
   details: "Authorization token not passed" type:"ValidationError"
```

I have done some googling and I think the error occurs because I didn't set the header object for the application. I may be wrong though.

Please i'll appreciate any assistance on how I can resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Are you using fetch requests?

Comment: i'm using axios @Meir

Comment: Can you see if the request has "Authorization" as request Headers and token is passed as value to this header in every post and get request henceforth.

Comment: @tarzenchugh  this is the response
Object
token
:
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImNvZGVidWdzb2x2ZWMTUzMDE5MTk5Nn0._lUcB5K-1tCoYJSE"
user
:
{created: "2018-06-05T14:58:57.862Z", phone: "..", email: ".....", name: "....."}

Answer (score 2):

axios, same as fetch, can accept a second parameter with config, part of which can be the auth token, so, you can pass in something like this:

```
axios.get(url, {
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${auth_token}`
    other_header1: 'value',
    other_header2: 'value2'
  }
}
```

Alternatively, upon getting your token, you can set it as a default value, look for 'config defaults' in [axios docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Comment: Thanks for the lead. i went through the doc and fixed it with this line of code                
       axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
      axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';